# What's wring with sending large json HTTP responses?

Tags: json, http, response

I'm requesting a webservice with an HTTP GET that sends back a large response in json format.
This response can vary from 100MB to few hundreds MB ...

What's in your opinions arguments I have to justify that this is not a good option to send back responses that way ?
Any W3C recommendations or so ?

- Blocking process
- Timeouts
- Unknown response size
  ...

Thanks for your thoughts

Comment: Seems to me like it could open you up to malicious users hitting your server for lots of resources and really slowing things down.

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to engineer the GET to return a list of URIs, with the json data segmented for the client to request in a non blocking fashion.